# Sounds are missing even though mixer shows signal. Speakers work while using live-usb or via graphic installer

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, speakers, pavucontrol

Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa
Asus T100TA x86 64bit

Hi everyone, since I used my laptop with a HDMI, the speakers and the headphones stopped making sounds. I checked both alsamixer and pavucontrol but all the needed channels are enabled and the mixer bar from the setting/sounds shows signal going. I tried to reinstall the OS and while I was installing I heard all the system sounds, such as: start up, errors, shut down etc, so I would exclude a hardware problem. Did anyone have such problem? How did you solved it?
Thank you

Comment: *since I used my laptop with a HDMI* suggests the default output changed to HDMI. It should be a matter to select the intended audio output at settings > sound, NOT mess with something you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing distro; now I'm using Mint and it does not break the audio when I use HDMI.